# How to updated PreHeader in TriggeredSend using SSJS

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud

I am trying to dynamically update Pre-Header in the email associated with a Triggered Send to send email out to subscribers. When I execute the code below, the PreHeader gets updated in the email but not in Triggered Send.

Hence the old Pre-Header goes out in emails. Can anyone advice?

Thanks

```
var status = myEmail.Update({ "Subject" : "Dummy Subject", "PreHeader" : "What!"});

var triggeredSend = TriggeredSend.Init("ABCD_TS");

triggeredSend.Pause();

var updateStatus = triggeredSend.Update({ "PreHeader" : "What!" });

var tsStatus = triggeredSend.Publish();

triggeredSend.Start();

var emailStatus = triggeredSend.Send(REFEREE_EMAIL);
```

Comment: If you look in the Marketing Cloud interface at the Triggered Email Definition, does it show that the PreHeader was updated?  I am wondering if it is an issue with the Update step or the Publish step and that would help narrow it down.

Comment: Another option, if the PreHeader is something that changes often, it could be made dynamic so that a value could be passed in through the request that triggers the email.  Create a new profile attribute called DynamicPreHeader, then in the PreHeaderField for the Triggered Email Definition, put %%PreHeaderField%%, then in the API call pass a value for PreHeaderField just like any normal attribute.